# java Quartz2 cron trigger is not firing immediately

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I need to execute scheduler immediately when I will call the scheduler and next time it will execute base on the cron expression. But here my code which is only executing after 10 minute but not executing when I run this class/application.

**QuartzConfigure.java** for registering and calling the execute method:

```
public class QuartzConfigure {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // specify the job' s details..
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzSchduleJob.class)
                                  .withIdentity("testJob")
                                  .build();

        //this is specify using chron expression using chrone expression
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("Group2")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 /10 * * * ?"))
            .startNow().build();

        //schedule the job
        SchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sch = schFactory.getScheduler();
        sch.start();
        sch.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

**QuartzSchduleJob.java** for job:

```
public class QuartzSchduleJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {        
         System.out.println("calling jobSchedulling::"+System.currentTimeMillis());     
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, your 'scheduler' starts immediatly after `sch.start()`, so I am guessing you want to know how force your Job to trigger when your 'scheduler' starts.

If so, you can not achieve this with only a cron expression but I have two solutions for you.

1. If you want your Job to be trigger at start and then every ten minutes after, consider using a `SimpleScheduleBuilder`. In your code, replace the `CronExpressionSchedule` :

   ```
   Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                         .withIdentity("trigger1", "Group2")
                         .withSchedule(ScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                             .withIntervalInMinutes(10)
                             .repeatForever())
                         .startNow()
                         .build();
   ```
2. If you want your Job to trigger at start and then fires on a scheduling based on your Cron expression. Consider using a second trigger :

   ```
   [...]
   Trigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                          .withIdentity("trigger2", "Group2")
                          .withSchedule(ScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule())
                          .startNow()
                          .build();
   [...]
   sch.start();
   sch.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
   sch.scheduleJob(job, trigger2);
   ```